# Drupal db select IN, group by count

Tags: 7, database

need a bit of help please, when i write my query like this it works fine

```
    $query = db_query('select * from form_submissions where address in (select address from form_submissions group by address having count(address) > 1 ');
    $submissions = $query->execute();
```

but when i write it with drupal it should work like this? but it dont

```
    $query = db_select('form_submissions', 'sfs')->fields('sfs', array());
    $subquery = db_select('form_submissions', '')->fields('address', array())->groupBy('address')->having('count(address) > 1');
    $query->condition('address', $subquery, 'in');

    $submissions = $query->execute();
```

can someone see what im doing wrong?

Comment: i solved it needed to put address in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $query = db_select('form_submissions', 'sfs')->fields('sfs', array());
    $subquery = db_select('form_submissions', 'sfs')->fields('sfs', array('address'))->groupBy('address')->having('count(address) > 1');
    $query->condition('address', $subquery, 'in');

    $submissions = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
$query = db_select('form_submissions', 'sfs')
    ->fields('sfs');
$subquery = db_select('form_submissions', 'subsfs')
    ->fields('subsfs', array('address'))
    ->groupBy('subsfs.address')
    ->addExpression('COUNT(subsfs.address)', 'countAddress')
    ->havingCondition('countAddress', 1, '>');

$query->condition('sfs.address', $subquery, 'IN');

    $submissions = $query->execute();
```